# How can I make toast notifications stay on screen longer?

Tags: toast-notifications

I occasionally have a toast notification that is too long to read in the given amount of time that it is displayed. Is there any way to change the length of time these notifications display?

Also, is there any way to view these notifications after they are gone?  This would be ideal, like an app or a folder that logs all the toast notifications where I can review them later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple Answer: No, this isn't possible.

Long Answer:

Toasts are built into apps, and are low level. There is no way for 3rd party apps to catch toasts, and there is no way to view them longer.

This could be possible if you made your own custom ROM however.

Answer (score 5):

The values of [`LENGTH_SHORT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#LENGTH_SHORT) and [`LENGTH_LONG`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#LENGTH_LONG) are 0 and 1.  This means they are treated as flags rather than actual durations so I don't think it will be possible to set the duration to anything other than these values.

If you want to display a message to the user for longer, consider a [Status Bar Notification](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).  Status Bar Notifications can be programmatically cancelled when they are no longer relevant.

Answer (score 1):

The currently accepted answer stands obsolete, now that there are handful of apps offering solutions for copying notifications and toasts for later use. I use [Toast Source](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.revanmj.toastsource) and it has worked well so far. You can find alternative apps in Play Store.

Install Toast Source, enable its service, let it observe the toasts which you can view them later under Saved toasts option.

As for extending the duration of the toasts, an Xposed based solution could probably help here. [XToast](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.vikas.toaststyler) claims to change a toast's duration. I have not tried this so I cannot vouch for it.

Answer (score 0):

No, however some apps lets you set a time that a toast message stays on screen.

(...I think.)

Comment: What apps? I find this hard to believe, since the code used to show toasts has only two constants for the duration, `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` and `Toast.LENGTH_LONG`. The entire Toast class would need to be overridden to allow custom lengths.

Comment: @onik - Some devs create their own `Dialog` implementations that mimic toasts both functionally and visually, but with custom timings. Not a true toast, but the end-user doesn't know that.

Answer (score -2):

If you enable engineer mode under quality enhancements you can change display toast time and notification time

Comment: How? Please provide a detailed answer with Android model and version it is tested upon?